# Matching any amount of words regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to capture a line with n-number of words that follow a title sequence in PHP, but I cannot capture anything more than the first word. Here are the contents of the file that I am trying to match:

```
Name: test
Caption: test test test test
```

And here is the regular expression code and results...

```
preg_match_all('/([A-z]+:)\s*(\w+)[\r|\r\n|\n]*/', $contents, $array);
```

Results:

```
array(3) { 
    [0]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(11) "Name: test " 
        [1]=> string(14) "Caption: test " 
    } 

    [1]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(5) "Name:" 
        [1]=> string(8) "Caption:" 
    } 

    [2]=> array(2) { 
       [0]=> string(4) "test" 
       [1]=> string(4) "test" 
    } 
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't `(?(\w+)\W+)+` work?

Comment: `[\r|\r\n|\n]*` also isn't a group, but matches line breaks `\r` or `\n` and the `|` bar thingy. You'd probably want to use `\s*` there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your input data always looks like your example (title segment, colon, words; all on a single line), this should do it:

```
preg_match_all('/([A-Za-z]+:)\s*(.*)/', $contents, $array);
```

This would result in `$array[1]` matching something like `Name:`, and then `$array[2]` would match the rest of the line (you may have to use `trim()` to strip any leading and/or trailing white space from `$array[2]`).

If you only want to capture "words" in the second part, I believe you could change the second capture group to something like:

```
preg_match_all('/([A-Za-z]+:)\s*([\w\s]+)/', $contents, $array);
```

Note also that you shouldn't use the `[A-z]` construct, since there are non-alphabetical characters in the ASCII table between the upper case letters and the lower case letters. See the [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for a character map.